# jQuery mobile listviews lazy loading

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can i implement lazy loading in mobile jquery lisview widget?
can anybody give a example using static data in json format binding to jquery mobile listview widget?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways, The following two ways work great

JQM way, a great tutorial. It detects when you scrolled to the bottom of the listview and loads more items to list

http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/infinite-scrolling/

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pAgbT/light/

Another way is to use Iscroll 5 plugging. Similarly you can setup a function to detect when you scrolled to the bottom of the list and load new items

http://iscrolljs.com/

**Demo** I placed the whole Iscroll 5 plugging in the demo so scroll down to //// JQM STUFF to see the actual code

Some of the JQM code e.g trigger create is depreciated in JQM 1.4 so some modifications are needed above > 1.4 for it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/t0t3Lz5x/

```
var myScroll;

 $(document).ready(function(){ 

        myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper',
                        {
                            scrollX: false, 
                            scrollY: true
                            ,click:true // open click event
                            ,scrollbars: false 
                            ,useTransform: true
                            ,useTransition: false
                            ,probeType:3,
                            mouseWheel:true,
                            bindToWrapper: true
        });

});


 function initscroll() {

    setTimeout(function () {
            myScroll.refresh();
        }, 1000);
    }




        output = '<li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li><li><a>Item</a></li>';
$('#listview').html(output).listview().listview('refresh');
 initscroll()   

myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
if (this.y  == this.maxScrollY)

load_new_items();

});

function load_new_items() {

mysearchlist = $('<li><a>New Item</a></li><li><a>New Item</a></li><li><a>New Item</a></li><li><a>New Item</a></li>');
mysearchlist.appendTo("#listview").trigger('create'); 
$('#listview').listview().listview('refresh');
 initscroll()      

}
```

There is one more way using the Jquery's **on scroll**  function to monitor the height of the list and then as you scroll measure the pixels you scrolled from the top of the list. When both match you can run a function to append more items in the list