# Swipe a div prints a message and disappear instead of display another div ( PhoneGap 2.9 - Android )

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, swipe

I want to have a swipe function in my first html page of the mobile application that I am implementing. 
I use Phonegap 2.9 and Eclipse. For this function, I used from [this](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/tree/master/demos) files the `Page_scrolling.html` and the JavaScripts it calls.

---

My head in `.html` file that I want to have the swipe function:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">

<title>Guide-Me For-All</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand|Permanent+Marker|Exo|Nunito|Limelight|Ubuntu|Montserrat|Audiowide|Architects+Daughter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- import stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/home/home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/home/home-eng-fonts.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme-master/themes/Bootstrap.css">

<!-- <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
 <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- import js --> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../jss/connect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../jss/home/change_page.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../plugins/js/main.js"></script>

<script src="../../plugins/swipe.js"></script>
```

According to the link, I needed the last `.css` link and the last four `.js` links. The forth JavaScript is the one that is inside the `Page_scrolling.html` in the tutorial I put above. The only file that I changed, is the last JavaScript:

---

My `Swipe.js` contains :

```
$(function() {      
  $("#trust_us").swipe( { swipeLeft:swipe2, swipeRight:swipe2} );
  $("#how_it_works").swipe( { swipeLeft:swipe2, swipeRight:swipe2} );
  $("#owners").swipe( { swipeLeft:swipe2, swipeRight:swipe2} );
  $("#sign_up_in").swipe( { swipeLeft:swipe2, swipeRight:swipe2} );
  //Swipe handlers.
  function swipe1(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
    $(this).text( "You have swiped " + direction +' with ' + fingerCount +' fingers' );
  }

  function swipe2(event, phase, direction, distance) {
    $(this).text( phase +" you have swiped " + distance + "px in direction:" + direction );
  }
});

//{ swipeStatus:swipe2, allowPageScroll:"horizontal"}
```

---

My `body` file is divided in the divs I want to swipe:

```
 <body> 
    <div id="logo">
        <img id="lg" src="../../imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo">    
    </div>


    <div id="trust_us">
        <div id="trust_us_h2">
            <h3>Why you should trust us :</h3>
        </div>
                            
        <ul>
            <li><p>All the info about the shops, are being validated with their owners.</p></li>
            <li><p>You can send your thoughts or complaints to the shops' owners, so that they will do improvements to it. *</p></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="notice">*Only for occasions when there was a contact between administrator - shop's owner!</div>   
    </div> <!--trust us-->

    <div id="how_it_works">
        <div id="how_it_works_h2">
            <h3>How it works :</h3>
        </div>
                                
        <div id="first">
            <h5>First:</h5>
        </div>
                                                        
        <div id="Sign_Up" class="float-left">
            <img  src="../../imgs/1sign-up.png" alt="Sign-Up">
            <p>  1. Register</p>
        </div>
                                                    
        <div id="Rate" class="float-right">
            <img  src="../../imgs/5rate.png" alt="Rate">    
            <p>5. Rate it according to your experience</p>
        </div>  
                                                    
    </div> <!--how it works-->


    <div id="owners">
        <div id="owners_h2">
            <h3>For the owners of a shop :</h3>
        </div>
                                                
        <ol>
            <li><p>Register</p></li>
            <li><p>After that, you can take interesting reports and useful statistics about your shop. *</p></li>
            <li><p>Now, you can do improvements to your shop according to what the customers need so you can get even more of them.</p></li>
        </ol>

        <div id="notice">*Contact the admin of the app for more information.</div>
    </div> <!--owners-->

    <div id="sign_up_in">
        <h2>...REGISTER NOW OR SIGN IN...</h2>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-icon="heart" onclick="change_page();">Sign-Up Now!</a>
    </div>

    
    <div id="last_line">
        <br>
    </div>
    
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2014 Guide-Me For-All. Design by Marialena S.</p>
    </div>
 </body>
```

---

What Is happening right now, Is when I swipe to the left or to the right a `div`, it disappears and in it's place it appears a message. And all the divs are in a vertical row. There are all viewable from the start when you scroll the page. What I want now, is when I swipe to the right the first `div` for example, to display the second `div`. In the same way I want to do the swipe to left function to display the previous `div`. That's all. I tried many other options but this looks the most simple.

Comment: Swipe pages or Scrolling down the page? if its for scrolling have a look at this question i answered --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968141/jquery-mobile-listviews-lazy-loading/25968972#25968972

Comment: The specific example does both swipe and scrolling....
Scrolling is working as I checked now (I will update my css), but the swipe does't work. The one page is down of another.

Comment: you don't really need Iscroll-swipe for UP DOWN swipes. there is a function for JQM to do that. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile -- you just the need to animate how many pixels you want to scroll down or up after the swipe.

Comment: and how about my `.html` file? what do I have to write there? I mean in my example, i divide to `<div id="page" ...` the parts that I want to swipe

Comment: Yes exactly. give your pages or elements id's and then create a function eg ($( '#page1" ).on("swipeup", function(){ scroll to next page or elenment });)  -- check here for an example how to use iscroll to scroll to another element or check SO on how to do that-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448992/scroll-to-element-in-iscroll -- becareful though because you are mixing iscroll with a swipe up so they may get confused between the 2 events ie scrolling and swipeing

Comment: In the second link you sent me, I managed to run the [code](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/tree/master/demos) I needed that was in a comment( a link). It detects the swipe movement. I used only the `Page_scrolling.html` from those files and the `JavaScripts` it calls . In the JavaScript, the important code is this: `$("#trust_us").swipe( swipeLeft:swipe2, swipeRight:swipe2} );` as you can check in the example. But, it does only call a function that prints a message on the div's place after I swipe a div. I only want to change the divs. And, I don't want iScroll at last.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the solution to my problem but I found [***this***](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) very nice tutorial and it's *really simple* to to do the swipe function.
 But if anyone finds my mistakes to the above code, please post the answer so that I can learn how to do the swipe function with this method too.